# Canvas Image Smoothing

Tags: image, webkit, canvas

What is

> ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;

for webkit(or other browsers)? I need it to remove anti-aliasing because i am trying to get a pixelized effect to an image. With anti-aliasing, it looks bad-quality but with no sharp edges.

Comment: You know, with pixel-art jagged is good, and smooth is bad. I'm looking for the same issue, and have not found webkit equivalents.

Comment: ```ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled=false``` works now in Chrome 22

Answer (score 9):

For the `<canvas>` tag, WebKit nightlies after r117635 and Chrome Canary 21.0.1154.0 now have a webkitImageSmoothingEnabled attribute.  (Note that this applies only to `<canvas>`, not to HTML elements more generally.)

Comment: Actually, you want to apply this to the 2D context of the canvas, not the canvas element itself. `var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;` or `ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`

Comment: @Fritzy - this doesn't do anything in Chrome 21

Comment: Still doesn't do anything for me in v27 (windows)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to draw shape without smooth edges try to use half pixels on coordinates.

> Imagine each pixel as a large square. The whole-number coordinates
>   (0, 1, 2…) are the edges of the squares. If you draw a one-unit-wide
>   line between whole-number coordinates, it will overlap opposite sides
>   of the pixel square, and the resulting line will be drawn two pixels
>   wide. To draw a line that is only one pixel wide, you need to shift
>   the coordinates by 0.5 perpendicular to the line's direction.
>
> For example, if you try to draw a line from (1, 0) to (1, 3), the
>   browser will draw a line covering 0.5 screen pixels on either side of
>   x=1. The screen can’t display half a pixel, so it expands the line to
>   cover a total of two pixels:
>
> [image]
>
> But, if you try to draw a line from (1.5, 0) to (1.5, 3), the browser
>   will draw a line covering 0.5 screen pixels on either side of x=1.5,
>   which results in a true 1-pixel-wide line:
>
> [image]

Source: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

Answer (score 2):

[**AFAIK**](http://www.mail-archive.com/whatwg@lists.whatwg.org/msg10074.html) no way yet. You might get the same effect drawing what you want pixel-by-pixel, but with more work (hey, not that much if it's something like lines).

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the link reported by Stephan below shows the following update to this issue on the bug tracker:

> The proposed value for CSS3's image-rendering 'optimize-contrast' has been implemented as '-webkit-optimize-contrast' in bug 56627. Right now in WebKit, using this will get you nearest-neighbour interpolation.

So the CSS setting `-webkit-optimize-contrast` looks to be the answer.

Comment: This is now ignored by Chrome :/ (I'm guessing all webkit)

Answer (score 1):

There is a (almost one year old) [bug report in webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40881) about this. One other possiblity would be to create your pixel art in higher resolutions and scale them down. This would probably yield better results than upsizing, but would be combined with higher traffic demands.

Answer (score 1):

Round your X and Y before showing your images on screen.

If you draw images on sub-pixels some browsers will try to anti-alias it before showing the image.

The faster way to do it is a binary `OR` with zero.

```
myObject.X = myObject.X | 0;
```

For a deeper explanation, take a read at this article:

http://sebleedelisle.com/2011/02/html5-canvas-sprite-optimisation/

And here is a jsperf test on rounding methods:

http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/5

Comment: Seems `myObject.X = myObject.X >> 0` Is a little faster.  Note that both of these will act like `Math.floor`, not `Math.round`

Comment: @UpTheCreek The absolute fastest: `myObject.X = ~~myObject.X`. [See the jsperf](http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/110).

Comment: @rvighne: not on my machine with win7 chrome v32 apparently: *±0.23%
0.27% slower*

Comment: @UpTheCreek Huh, interesting (I saw your results in the BrowserScope). Also interesting is that `Math.floor` is consistently faster than `| 0`. This shakes everything I thought I knew about rounding hacks...