# Disable Interpolation when Scaling a <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

***NOTE***: This has to do with how *existing canvas elements are rendered when scaled up*, **not** to do with how lines or graphics are rendered *onto a canvas surface*. In other words, this has everything to do with *interpolation* of *scaled elements*, and nothing to do with *antialiasing* of graphics being drawn on a canvas. I'm not concerned with how the browser draws lines; I care about how the browser renders the canvas element *itself* when it is scaled up.

---

Is there a canvas property or browser setting I can change programmatically to disable interpolation when scaling `<canvas>` elements? A cross-browser solution is ideal but not essential; Webkit-based browsers are my main target. Performance is very important.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670084/canvas-image-smoothing) is most similar but does not illustrate the problem sufficiently. For what it's worth, I have tried `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast` to no avail.

The application will  be a "retro" 8-bit styled game written in HTML5+JS to make it clear what I need.

---

To illustrate, here is an example. ([live version](http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/))

Suppose I have a 21x21 canvas...

```
<canvas id='b' width='21' height='21'></canvas>
```

...which has css that makes the element 5 times larger (105x105):

```
canvas { border: 5px solid #ddd; }
canvas#b { width: 105px; height: 105px; } /* 5 * 21 = 105 */
```

I draw a simple 'X' on the canvas like so:

```
$('canvas').each(function () {
    var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(21,21);
    ctx.moveTo(0,21);
    ctx.lineTo(21,0);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

The image on the left is what Chromium (14.0) renders. The image on the right is what I want (hand-drawn for illustrative purposes).

[image: Chrome interpolates scaled canvas elements] [image: A non-interpolated version]

Comment: Somewhat related, though not identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element

Comment: I believe that question is referring to the line-drawing functions drawing anti-aliased lines. I'm referring to how resized canvas elements are rendered with interpolation by default.

Comment: Yes, sorry...I first thought the questions the same then immediately noticed my mistake.  :-/  What if you were to try using the pixelation filter of jsmanipulate?  http://www.joelb.me/jsmanipulate/

Comment: That's more of an image-filter meant for photographs.

Comment: Yes, but if it transforms your left image into a good enough version of your right image to make you happy then it could provide a cross-browser solution (considering it's not looking too promising to find a flag for this drawing mode, universal or otherwise, in WebKit).  Whether it's a viable substitute depends on the problem you are trying to solve...if you really need discrete pixel drawing or if you're just trying to ensure the result is pixelated with a certain granularity.

Comment: The `image-rendering` property that [is currently part of the CSS3 working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/#image-rendering) is the property I would be looking for (using a value of `optimize-contrast`). [It is implemented in Webkit as `-webkit-optimize-contrast`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56627) but the version of Chromium I use doesn't seem to use nearest-neighbor (yet?), nor is it currently implemented in any other browsers (to my knowledge).

Comment: [This is a fantastic, in-depth article](http://phoboslab.org/log/html5) about this issue and how the creator of ImpactJS "solved" it. The answer is kinda discouraging. :[

Answer (score 146, accepted):

### Last Updated: 2014-09-12

> Is there a canvas property or browser setting I can change programmatically to disable interpolation when scaling  elements?

The answer is *maybe some day*. For now, you'll have to resort to hack-arounds to get what you want.

---

### `image-rendering`

[The working draft of CSS3 outlines a new property, **`image-rendering`**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images/#the-image-rendering) that should do what I want:

> The image-rendering property provides a hint to the user-agent about what aspects of an image are most important to preserve when the image is scaled, to aid the user-agent in the choice of an appropriate scaling algorithm.

The specification outlines three accepted values: `auto`, `crisp-edges`, and **`pixelated`**.

> **pixelated:**
>
> When scaling the image up, the "nearest neighbor" or similar algorithm must be used, so that the image appears to be simply composed of very large pixels. When scaling down, this is the same as auto.

### Standard? Cross-browser?

Since this is merely a *working draft*, there's no guarantee that this will become standard. Browser support is currently spotty, at best.

The Mozilla Developer Network has [a pretty thorough page dedicated to the current state of the art](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Image-rendering) which I highly recommend reading.

The Webkit developers initially chose to [tentatively implement this as `-webkit-optimize-contrast`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56627), but Chromium/Chrome don't seem to be using a version of Webkit that implements this.

**Update: 2014-09-12**

[Chrome 38 now supports `image-rendering: pixelated`](http://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5118058116939776)!

Firefox has a [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=856337) open to get `image-rendering: pixelated` implemented, but `-moz-crisp-edges` works for now.

### Solution?

The most cross-platform, CSS-only solution so far is thus:

```
canvas {
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* Older versions of FF          */
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* FF 6.0+                       */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Safari                        */
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* OS X & Windows Opera (12.02+) */
  image-rendering: pixelated;                 /* Awesome future-browsers       */
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE                            */
}
```

Sadly this wont work on all major HTML5 platforms yet (Chrome, in particular).

Of course, one could manually scale up images using nearest-neighbor interpolation onto high-resolution canvas surfaces in javascript, or even pre-scale images server-side, but in my case this will be forbiddingly costly so it is not a viable option.

[ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com) uses a texture pre-scaling technique to get around all this FUD. Impact's developer, Dominic Szablewski, [wrote a very in-depth article about this](http://phoboslab.org/log/2012/09/drawing-pixels-is-hard) (he even ended up citing this question in his research).

See [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751817/742156) for a canvas-based solution that relies on the `imageSmoothingEnabled` property (not available in older browsers, but simpler than pre-scaling and pretty widely-supported).

### Live Demo

If you'd like to test the CSS properties discussed in the MDN article on `canvas` elements, I've made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/VAXrL/1459/) which should display something like this, blurry or not, depending on your browser:
[image: a 4:1 (64x64 to 256x256) image of an isometric pixel-art style TV]

Comment: Image-rendering seems to work elsewhere, but webkit browsers. I really hope that Chrome/Chromium/Safari staff reads well what "switch to EPX interpolation in low-load situations" means. When I first read the sentence I thought that optimize-contrast allows new colors created in low load, but NO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#EPX.2FScale2.C3.97.2FAdvMAME2.C3.97

Comment: Opera 12.02 on Mac and Windows supports image-rendering:-o-crisp-edges  ( http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/21/ ), so you could add it on your answer.

Comment: Is it supposed to work when I'm increasing the browser zoom? I've tested drawing with FF 22, Chrome 27 and IE 10 on Windows 7 when the browser zoom is 150% and the result is blurry on all browsers. When I double the canvas width and height and set it back to the original width and height with CSS it draws sharp lines.

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure if there's a spec for user-specified scaling behavior.

Comment: Chrome still doesn't seem to support pixelated. Or at least it doesn't work in my Chrome Canary 40.0.2175.0

Comment: I’m (from the present future!) on Chrome 78. I’m seeing “image-rendering: pixelated;” working. It looks like this was added in 2015 to Chrome 41: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/pixelated

Answer (score 69):

**New answer 7/31/2012**

This is finally in the canvas spec!

The specification has recently added a property called `imageSmoothingEnabled`, which defaults to `true` and determines if images drawn on non-integer coordinates or drawn scaled will use a smoother algorithm. If it is set to `false` then nearest-neighbor is used, producing a less smooth image and instead just making larger looking pixels.

Image smoothing has only recently been added to the canvas specification and isn’t supported by all browsers, but some browsers have implemented vendor-prefixed versions of this property. On the context there exists `mozImageSmoothingEnabled` in Firefox and `webkitImageSmoothingEnabled` in Chrome and Safari, and setting these to false will stop anti-aliasing from occurring. Unfortunately, at the time of writing, IE9 and Opera have not implemented this property, vendor prefixed or otherwise.

---

Preview: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ikaruss/VAXrL/1164/)**

Result:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this doesn't work yet, either. Maybe I'm missing something? Here's a test: http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/187/

Comment: you have to scale using the canvas API for it to work, you can't scale with CSS ever and have the canvas API affect it! So something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/190/

Comment: But the nature of this problem isn't really about canvas. It's about how the browser renders scaled images, including <canvas> elements.

Comment: If you scale using CSS, namuol's solution will work.  If you scale the image manually onto the Canvas, Simon's solution works.  It's neat that there are solutions for both cases, so thanks to you both!

Comment: For IE 11: msImageSmoothingEnabled works for me! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265062(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Note: The `ctx.drawImage` call does not work anymore (tested in Chrome/Firefox) without waiting for a png.onload event, even though it's only a data url. Quick fix for the example snippet: 

`png.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(png, 0, 0, this.width, this.height); }`

Comment: Yes, Shaun is right - only CSS `image-rendering: pixelated;` now (2020) works.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit 7/31/2012 - This functionality is now in the canvas spec! See separate answer here:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751817/154112

Old answer is below for posterity.

---

Depending on your desired effect, you have this as one option:

```
var can = document.getElementById('b');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
ctx.scale(5,5);
$('canvas').each(function () {
    var ctx = this.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(21,21);
    ctx.moveTo(0,21);
    ctx.lineTo(21,0);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wa95p/

Which creates this:

[image]

Probably not what you want. But if you were merely looking to have zero blur then that would be the ticket so I'll offer it just in case.

A more difficult option is to use pixel manipulation and write an algorithm yourself for the job. Each pixel of the first image becomes a 5x5 block of pixels on the new image. It wouldn't be too hard to do with imagedata.

But Canvas and CSS alone won't help you here for scaling one to the other with the exact effect you desire.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Apparently, `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast` should do the trick but doesn't seem to do anything. I may look into rolling a function to scale up a canvas' contents using nearest-neighbor interpolation.

Comment: I originally accepted your answer; I revoked it for now because there seems to be confusion about whether this is a duplicate or not.

Comment: I have a more complete answer after doing some research and would like to reopen the question to provide my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In google chrome, canvas image patterns aren't interpolated.

Here is a working example edited from the namuol answer http://jsfiddle.net/pGs4f/

```
ctx.scale(4, 4);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
```

Comment: This is the most attractive workaround I've seen so far. Not sure about performance yet, but it's totally worth looking into. I'll try it out.

Comment: using repeat instead of no-repeat is faster. Don't know why.
It's also pretty fast, three.js use this in CanvasRenderer

Comment: update: no longer works with chrome 21 (due to the retina display support added?)

new version http://jsfiddle.net/saviski/pGs4f/12 using imageSmoothingEnabled pointed by Simon

Comment: When Retina resolution comes general, things changes enormously. When iPhone4-5 style 326dpi (128dpcm) Retina display comes to 24 inch (52x32cm) monitors, the screen size will be 6656 x 4096 px. Then antialiasing is bad, and all browser vendors (even Webkit based) is forced to allow disabling antialiasing. Antialiasing is cpu-intensive operation and antialiasing 6656 x 4096 px image would be too slow, but fortunately unnecessary in such display.

Comment: Just as a side-note, here's a good benchmark aboout patterns vs image: http://jsperf.com/drawimage-vs-canvaspattern/9

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is set the [`image-rendering: pixelated`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) CSS property on the `<canvas>`. This is now supported by all browsers. (https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_image-rendering_pixelated)

Comment: Namuol's answer is great. But in 2022 you can just set this property and not worry about the history of the feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Saviski's workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/saviski/pGs4f/12) explicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421777/1691517) is promising, because it works on:

- Chrome 22.0.1229.79 Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Chrome 22.0.1229.79 m Windows 7
- Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 11.10
- Firefox 3.6.25 Windows 7

But not works in the following, but the same effect can be achieved using CSS image-rendering:

- Firefox 15.0.1 Mac OS X 10.6.8 (image-rendering:-moz-crisp-edges works in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/21/) )
- Opera 12.02 Mac OS X 10.6.8 (image-rendering:-o-crisp-edges works in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/21/) )
- Opera 12.02 Windows 7 (image-rendering:-o-crisp-edges works in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VAXrL/21/) )

The problematic are these, because ctx.XXXImageSmoothingEnabled is not working and image-rendering is not working:

- Safari 5.1.7 Mac OS X 10.6.8. (image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast NOT works)
- Safari 5.1.7 Windows 7 (image-rendering:-webkit-optimize-contrast NOT works)
- IE 9 Windows 7 (-ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor NOT works)