# How to save an image of size a*a in HTML5 canvas, canvas.toDataURL() and later draw it in different sizes, a*a / 2a*2a?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How to save a single image of size `a * a` using HTML5 canvas, `canvas.toDataURL()` and later draw it in different sizes,  `a * a` / `2a * 2a` without distortion?

*OR*

I have a HTML5 / JavaScript web application. There is an item catalogue, in which when I add a new item, I add an image of the item using HTML5 canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvasnew" height="100" style="border:1px dotted" width="100"></canvas>
```

This `100 * 100` image is converted to `$('#canvasnew')[0].toDataURL()` and saved in my database. And the image is later drawn into another canvas like this:

```
var ctx = $(this.el).find('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = this.model.toJSON().ImageUrl;`
```

`this.model.toJSON().ImageUrl` gets the image (size `100 * 100`)saved in dataUrl form. Now, I need to draw this same image into one more canvas of size `400 * 400` without distortion. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 400, 400);
```

`drawImage` accepts up to 9 parameters, [the first 5 being](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Using_images#Scaling):

1. The image,
2. x position,
3. y position,
4. width,
5. height.

So: `drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);`

Stretching a image like that will, however, always result in some sort of distortion, due to "new" pixels having to be calculated / interpolated. Some interpolation algorithms are more efficient, or result in better images than others, but so far the `canvas` has limited support for different algorithms. ([Take a look here for some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas))