# How to resize a canvas without anti-aliasing?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, livescript

**Update**

It's definitely to do with how I'm rescaling the canvas. If I draw the same scene onto a canvas and I don't change it's width and height to fill the screen, it works perfectly.

[image: Working]

What is the correct way to resize a canvas for fullscreen environments?

---

I'm writing a game engine for canvas and am having problems with images being upscaled and aliased, I read through a couple of answers for people having similar problems. I amended my code to enable the following settings on each of my canvases.

```
context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;                                                                                
context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;                                                                                   
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

Just to make sure, I also included the CSS alternatives of these rules.

```
canvas {
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             // Older versions of FF
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          // FF 6.0+
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; // Webkit (non standard naming)
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            // OS X & Windows Opera (12.02+)
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;               // Possible future browsers.
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   // IE (non standard naming)
}
```

Here's an example of one of the original images I am trying to draw.

[image: Character]

I'm then upscaling from 16x16 to 64x64 and instead of coming out looking like nearest-neighbour interpolation was used, it renders like this.

[image: Actual result]

I get the same results in Chrome and Firefox. I don't want to do a preprocessing step to upscale the images, either. It's got to be possible, because [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/TYUUJ/) works for me.

The other thing to mention, is that the engine is designed to be used in fullscreen, so I am manually keeping the size of the canvases up to date with this function.

```
fill-screen = (canvas) ->
  canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth
  canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight
```

The canvases are absolutely positioned to the top left hand corner of their parent, other than that, there are no non-browser CSS rules operating on them.

Maybe I'm doing something stupid, but I've been looking at this for ages and I'm getting no closer. The code for the file where I am creating the canvases and contexts is here: https://gist.github.com/code-curve/9273248

Comment: @sebcap26 There is a fiddle.

Comment: @Dan Prince - maybe this question can give you some more info to solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas

Comment: Can you give some HTML / JS code ?

Comment: @enguerranws There's a lot of code, is there something you want to look at in specific?

Comment: If I understand well, you want a pixellized result and not a smoothed one ? I can't test your image from here because of a stupid proxy, but when I run your fiddle with another image (https://ixquick.com/graphics/ixquick_res.gif) on firefox 27, the second canvas is not smoothed.

Comment: @sebcap26 That fiddle is just there to demonstrate that it's not a problem with my browser. That fiddle works for me, but something in my code doesn't.

Comment: @Dan Prince We need a non working fiddle to help you.

Comment: I wanna check how you define "context", and what it is, as we can't see it now.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong when you post working code and just say "my code doesn't work"  :)

Comment: @sebcap26, zyklus I can't just put it in a fiddle, it's a full game engine which is loading local resources and json files over http. I can gist or fiddle any bits of code you want to see though.

Comment: @enguerranws Canvas and Context creation is here: https://gist.github.com/code-curve/9273248

Comment: Partial progress, any suggestions on how I should be resizing my canvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you resize the canvas the smoothing setting is reset as well (may depend on browser).

After you resize the canvas simply re-apply the `imageSmoothingEnabled`.

```
fill-screen = (canvas) ->
  canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth
  canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight
  // re-apply here on context
```

I would also recommend using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` instead for the sizes.

My (free) [retro context library](https://github.com/AbdiasSoftware/Canvas-Retro-Context) may also be of interest.

Comment: Are you able to link any documentation explaining the potential smoothing reset?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find an "actual" solution, you can always just scale up the graphics yourself:

```
var ctxData = ctx.getImageData()
  ,  pixels = ctxData.data
  ,   width = 16
  ,  height = 16
  ,    mult = 4
  ;

for( var x=width*mult-1; x>=0; x-- ){
    for( var y=height*mult-1; y>=0; y-- ){

        // or something close to this
        pixels[ y*width*mult*4 + x ] = pixels[ y*width*4 + x ];
    }
}

// pseudo code
canvas.width  *= mult;
canvas.height *= mult;

ctx.putImageData( ctxData );
```

Comment: Appreciated, but there's got to be an actual solution, because the fiddle I linked to works for me.