# EaselJS - "Pixely" rendering as opposed to smooth

Tags: rendering, pixel, easeljs

Is there a way in EaselJS to create a pixelated render as opposed to the normal smooth/ antialiased way? The style of the project calls for a design as described. I'm namely trying to make paths appear to have edges when on an angle.

Another alternative would be to render a bunch of rectangles along where the path would be and offset them slightly in order to make it appear pixelated, but I'd rather not have to use multiple objects if there is an alternative method.

Comment: Are you looking for an aliased approach to drawing Graphics or scaled images? Some good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas

Comment: @Lanny I need to use it on Graphics in this case unfortunately.