# In EaselJS, how can I scale up pixel art without blurring it?

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I'm making a game in EaselJS using pixel art, which I'm scaling up. The problem is, when I scale it, it blurs the image. Is there a way to make it draw it using *nearest neighbor* filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in *canvas*, let alone EaselJS. There are emerging properties that might help accomplish this, and WebGL drawing may facilitate this as well (better WebGL support is imminent in EaselJS)

Check out this similar question/post.
[Disable Interpolation when Scaling a <canvas>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas)