# Render image as defined pixel squares HTML5 canvas?

Tags: python, html, canvas, interpolation, factory

I have the following 6x5 image:

[image: 6x5 image]

Which appears as so blown up on the canvas:

[image: canvas screenshot]

I render it using more or less this code `this.context.putImageData(this.imageData, 0, 0)` and scale the canvas with css (`canvas {width: 100%}`).

It has the following rgb values:

```
51.65   41.59   60.74   159.44  137.91  165.41  
147.29  71.01   52.93   73.80   115.80  93.45   
77.16   112.66  98.07   70.43   78.91   107.27  
107.39  122.85  60.67   103.91  144.37  124.05  
138.59  123.77  140.51  107.25  52.10   138.80
```

Why can't I see the individuals as block squares in a defined grid? Is it something to do with how images are rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is related to how the images are rendered.

When you have an image with colors, you usually have the complete information of the color of every pixel. So a 100x100 image renders perfectly on a 100x100 pizel size.

But when you try to scale *UP* this image, you have more pixels available to fill but less *information* about *how* to fill them. So you resort to mathematical algorithms, usually known as **interpolation**.

Canvas will automatically interpolate the pixels to fill in gaps using nearest pixel information.

To get your desired effect of having single pixels, you need to scale up *without* any interpolation. To do this you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas), or rather find several answers now that you know the appropriate terms to exactly describe your problem.

This CSS3 solution should work in Chrome 41+ for now:

```
canvas {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```