# HTML5 Image quality after scaling bitmap is bad

Tags: html, image, bitmap, resize, easeljs

I am creating my first game in HTML 5 for mobile.

I'm just using the library "Easeljs-0.7.0", nothing PhoneGap.

I made my images to canvas 2024x1024 pixels, then each image by setting the scaleX and scaleY. However when the scale is less than 0.5 makes all images with poor quality.

How to solve this?

```
var test = new createjs.Bitmap("test.png");
test.scaleX = 0.23456;
test.scaleY = 0.23456;
APP.stage.addChild(test);
APP.stage.update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is how Canvas renders the bitmap, and its not something that can be controlled by JavaScript. It is possible to get some results in various browsers using the `context.imageSmoothingEnabled' property, but currently it requires vendor prefixes. Check out this thread: 
[Canvas Image Smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670084/canvas-image-smoothing)

To do this with EaselJS, you need to get the canvas context, which is not currently available without manually accessing it:

```
var context = myStage.canvas.getContext("2d");
context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;
```

Comment: It did not work. [Here is a screen shot of the game running on the iPhone simulator 5](http://imageshack.us/a/img9/6701/msry.png). (In iPhone does not seem to break much, however is without equal quality)